# Ignore Unicode Error

Tags: python, unicode, csv, ascii

When I run a loop over a bunch of URLs to find all links (in certain Divs) on those pages I get back this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "file_location", line 38, in <module>
out.writerow(tag['href'])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The code I have written related to this error is:

```
out  = csv.writer(open("file_location", "ab"), delimiter=";")
for tag in soup_3.findAll('a', href=True):   
    out.writerow(tag['href'])
```

**Is there a way to solve this, possibly using an if statement to ignore any URLs that have Unicode errors?**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap the writerow method call in a `try` and catch the exception to ignore it:

```
for tag in soup_3.findAll('a', href=True):
    try:
        out.writerow(tag['href'])
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        pass
```

but you almost certainly want to pick an encoding other than ASCII for your CSV file (utf-8 unless you have a very good reason to use something else), and open it with `codecs.open()` instead of the built-in `open`.

Comment: Thanks very much I used the try: and it worked which is great.

How do you change the encoding and why would you want to do that?

Please forgive this basic question but I am very new to programming.

Comment: Almost always, you don't want to just throw away data because it happens to use non-ASCII characters. If you open the file with `open("file_location", "ab","utf-8")`, instead of throwing a `UnicodeEncodeError`, `out.write` will write the actual data it read from the website, which 99% of the time is what you actually want.

Comment: Ah, that would help, when I add ,"utf-8" to the end of the current line that opens I get the error: TypeError: an integer is required

Should I use just open("file_location", "ab","utf-8"), and if so how can I introduce csv.writer so that it can be used in the "try:" section.

Thanks again for your help

Comment: oops; you want `codecs.open` (importing `codecs` first), not just `open`, as I said in the answer above but not in the example comment.